How to retrieve JSON string from the request body of POST method in Azure Functions?
From my JavaScript client, I send the JSON data using POST method
fetch("https://%$%$%%$.azurewebsites.net/api/JointPose?", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        JointPose1: `${Joint1Pose}`,
                        JointPose2: `${Joint2Pose}`,
                        JointPose3: `${Joint3Pose}`,
                        JointPose4: `${Joint4Pose}`,
                        JointPose5: `${Joint5Pose}`,
                        JointPose6: `${Joint6Pose}`,
                        JointPose7: `${Joint7Pose}`
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
                        }
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log('Success:', data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });

I try to retrieve the request body using HTTPtrigger in my Azure Functions app
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "JointPose")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
            string jointPoseData = ms.ToString();

            //using StreamReader reader = new(req.Body);
            //string bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            //var jointPoseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JointPoseData>(bodyStr);

            return new OkObjectResult( new { Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jointPoseData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") });
        }

public class JointPoseData
    {
        public string JointPose1 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose2 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose3 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose4 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose5 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose6 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose7 { get; set; }
    }


The response I get after opening the URL is
When opened the URL link in browser
Expected output is:
JointPose1: 0.31, JointPose2: 0.32,.......
Revised script for the function
[FunctionName("GetJointData")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> GetJointData(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "JointPose")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            using StreamReader reader = new(req.Body);
            string bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            await serviceHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("jointPose", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyStr));
            return new OkObjectResult(new
            {
                Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyStr)
            });
        }

I get this response in the console of my browser
Content is null
I think the jointPoseData is null. How do I retrieve the request body with appropriate values?

You are on the right track but there are some clarifications that I can make.
First, the code that you have commented to read the stream and convert it to a string is correct.
//using StreamReader reader = new(req.Body);
//string bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
//var jointPoseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JointPoseData>(bodyStr);

The code that you have uncommented for reading the stream would not work because of ms.ToString();. In C#, every class has a .ToString() method because every class is derived from Object which contains this method. Classes can override this method but by default it just outputs the name of the type. Therefore in your code the "ms" variable will just hold the value of "System.IO.MemoryStream".
Moving onto the return of the function, we need to use OkObjectResult which you have correctly used, and we can simply pass in the string into the constructor. In case you would like to have the string under the "Content" property, we can pass an anonymous object with the "Content" property and give the string as the value. StringContent would not be applicable here as it is a class used in HttpClients. It should also be noted that if all you mean to do is output the request body, there is no need to Deserialize and then Serialize back.
This results in the following code:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;

namespace Payments.PaymentInstrumentRouter
{
    public class TestingFunction
    { 
        [Function("TestingFunction")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            using StreamReader reader = new(req.Body);
            string bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            return new OkObjectResult(new
            {
                Content = bodyStr
            });
        }
    }
    public class JointPoseData
    {
        public string JointPose1 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose2 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose3 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose4 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose5 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose6 { get; set; }
        public string JointPose7 { get; set; }
    }
}

Now going onto calling the function. If you call the function using the script you have shared using the Chrome Dev tools or in postman, you should be able to see the output content with the request body:


Hopefully this has answered your question. Please share if there are any doubts.
EDIT:
In the comments, a question was asked which was "How can the data sent in the POST request body be viewed in a different request?
We can use a static variable to hold the value of the request body. Static variables are associated with the class itself rather than instances of the class, and hence they can be used to persist data across different requests. We can also add a conditional to set the value of this variable only if we are doing a POST request.
public class TestingFunction
{
    private static string RequestBody { get; set; }

    [Function("TestingFunction")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        using StreamReader reader = new(req.Body);
        string bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        if (req.Method == "POST")
        {
            RequestBody = bodyStr;
        }

        return new OkObjectResult(new
        {
            Content = RequestBody
        });
    }
}


thanks for your answer. After revising my function as per your suggestions I get Content=null. New script can be found above. Could you suggest anything?

The script is correct, but I have a question on where you are seeing Content=null. Are you saying that you see Content=null when you open the URL in the browser, or after you run your JS script?

after I deploy my function app on azure and open the url in the browser (LInk to the image: https://i.sstatic.net/CQbsTqrk.png)

When you open the app in the browser, you are not sending any request body right? Opening a site in the browser is just an empty GET request. If you want to send a POST request using the request body you should use Postman or use your script in the Chrome Dev Tools. Please reference my bottom two screenshots. You will see that in the first screen shot after opening the url in the browser Content = empty-string but I use your script in the Chrome Dev Tools to send a POST request with the data and get a valid response back.

No, I sent the POST request from the web client that is opened in another tab and then I opened the URL for this function to check if the joint poses are received

I am not sure in that case. My intuition would tell me that what you are attempting to do would require the following:


In your first POST call, save the request body to a static variable


Retrieve the value of this static variable in subsequence GET calls.


I feel that this is not what you are attempting since you have introduced "serviceHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync" which appears to be from SignalR and is not something I am familiar with. I would recommended making a new question and describing this new use case.

thanks for the recommendation. I am using SignalR but that has nothing to do with this because all I am looking to do is retrieve the URL body sent using the POST method to the azure function application.  I don't understand If my approach is valid, why I don't receive the data?

I feel that it is working but you have a misunderstanding on what you should see in the UI. Can you confirm that the Chrome Dev tools and Postman steps I have shared are working for you? If trying these steps is giving you the request body then the function is receiving the data.

Yes, I can confirm that using POSTMAN API works for me and I can receive the data in the response body. However, the aim is to see the data on the webpage when I open the URL. How do I achieve that?

In that case we can utilize a static variable to hold the request body contents. I have shared the new function-code which utilizes this method.
